# keycloak-domain-extension clean build does not work as expected when deployed

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, keycloak

We are having some issues with deploying the examples for keycloak extensions, more specifically this one:

[keycloak-domain-extension(GitHub)](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/providers/domain-extension)

We have imported the entire keycloak repo into IntelliJ using maven import.
Added a compiler version to the pom-file, since it defaulted to 1.5 some how…:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

now we are able to build a JAR artifact from IntelliJ

*but after deploying the jar to JBoss using the specified command from the README.md of the repo. we get:*

```
RESTEASY003815: Subresource for target class has no jax-rs annotations.: org.keycloak.examples.domainextension.rest.ExampleRestResource
```

Does this look familiar to someone? any ideas very appreciated…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When importing in IntelliJ i selected all the targets, if you only import the preselected/default targets build works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like IntelliJ's buildchain did something here,I just imported the pom-files, so IntelliJ probably needed some additional setup...

When building with mvn install in an external terminal and deploying according to the readme, everything seems to work.